Invalid key supplied at vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php in Laravel app
Stack: Laravel 11 - Ubuntu 24.04 - PHP 8.3 - Composer 2.7.1
I pulled a Laravel app from Gitlab and when running composer install I got this error:
Invalid key supplied at vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php

No matter which php artisan command I run, the same error shows up again and again.
BTW, there is no keys under storage directory.
Content of composer.json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.308",
        "dedoc/scramble": "^0.9.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.16",
        "google/apiclient-services": "^0.362.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
        "laravel/passport": "*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^13.6",
        "pkpass/pkpass": "^2.3",
        "rap2hpoutre/fast-excel": "^5.4",
        "saloonphp/laravel-http-sender": "^3.0",
        "saloonphp/laravel-plugin": "^3.0",
        "saloonphp/saloon": "^3.0",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^4.5",
        "spatie/laravel-data": "^4.6",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^11.4",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^3.0",
        "deployer/deployer": "*",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.15",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "11.1.3",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
            "@php -r \"file_exists('database/database.sqlite') || touch('database/database.sqlite');\"",
            "@php artisan migrate --graceful --ansi"
        ],
        "ide-helper": [
            "php artisan ide-helper:gen",
            "php artisan ide-helper:models --no-interaction --write --reset"
        ],
        "pint": [
            "./vendor/bin/pint"
        ],
        "clear-laravel-caches": [
            "@php artisan optimize:clear --env=testing"
        ],
        "refresh-testing-database": [
            "@php artisan qa:drop-parallel-test-databases --env=testing",
            "@php artisan migrate:fresh --env=testing"
        ],
        "test-coverage": [
            "@clear-laravel-caches",
            "@refresh-testing-database",
            "./vendor/bin/pest --coverage --parallel --recreate-databases"
        ],
        "test": [
            "@clear-laravel-caches",
            "@refresh-testing-database",
            "./vendor/bin/pest --parallel --recreate-databases"
        ],
        "test-coverage-xdebug": [
            "XDEBUG_MODE=coverage php artisan test --coverage"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}

I've read several posts about similar issues, but haven't found yet a solution.
Am I maybe missing something?

try php artisan key:generate before composer install

@ArjanShrestha as I said in my post, whatever php artisan command I try, the error shows up...

Could it be something related to permissions on storage directory?

I've just tried a chmod -R 777 storage but still having the same error...
